# Why can't I ask question?

Tags: support

I'm trying to ask question since few hours, and every time when I click `Post your question`, small dots on right start to animate, but else nothing happens. After some time I get a red frame with error text `an error occurred submitting your question`.

I tried both on Chrome and Firefox, even with Incognito mode enabled to exclude problem with cache.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: But u have posted it now na! :)

Comment: Yes, that's weird. I can post to meta, but cannot post to non-meta stack.

Comment: @Dodzik Could you add a screenshot for us please.

Comment: Sure, wait a few moments please. I reloaded it minute ago and now Im waiting for error to appear.

Comment: This sounds like a network error. Are you familiar with your browser's dev tools? If so, check the network tab to see what fails to load.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/axA3fMv). 
I will try to look into dev tools

Comment: @Yannis [this](http://i.imgur.com/YujsHtn.png) is output from network tab in chrome dev tools. Submit fails to load.

Comment: @Dodzik: You're behind a corporate firewall, right? It blocks the POST to `http://stackoverflow.com`. Did you try `https://stackoverflow.com` instead? (Note the additional S after HTTP)

Comment: @Zeta using https:// helped. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting a 522 error on the main site until just a few seconds ago. (Nope, I'm actually getting served a cached page now.)

Comment: StackOverflow has been up/down all morning